# How would I display posts from an asp file in the DOM?

Tags: dom, asp-classic

I'm creating a website where users submit text field entries and they are publicly displayed. I have the Javascript to submit the entry and post to a file on our servers ready. But, how do you take posts using the javascript "get" method and display them in the DOM? To clarify I'm taking text and picture entries from an asp file and display 10 of them in the DOM (empty divs in the HTML).

Answer (score 0):

Usually you save the submissions in a database, not files. Then query the same database to pull them back out. You can then fetch them in a page reload or use AJAX to load them into the current page.

Comment: Agreed, a database can give you much less headache than a file storage. You can sort, filter and edit or delete specific posts much easier. Try and have a look at SQLite, which has an ODBC driver you can use form classic ASP, plus several free windows management tools.